# How to get current request

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I try to construct the request class will got a initial request object not a current request object, how to initialize current request content?

```
$request = new \Zend\Http\Request;
echo $request->getUri()->toString(); //is empty
```

p.s. I don't want to use that Zend Framework mvc

Comment: The top result for 'zend get current request' goes to the documentation page.

Comment: At what point in your code are you using this code-snipped? From Controller level you can simply call `$this->getRequest()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Request to populate itself, use `\Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request`, otherwise you will need to set all the values manually.